# Trouble with div background repeat-x

Tags: css, background-image, repeat

Hey guys, I feel stupid with this one. I have one `<div>` that is set to some large width, spanning longer than the window view port and thus adding a horizontal scrollbar. Below that I have another `<div>`. This `<div>` has a simple image set as the `background-image` with `repeat-x`. I can't seem to get the second `<div>` to repeat the entire length of the preceding `<div>`. Take a look here: http://jsfiddle.net/5CW7T/.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### [See Example Here](http://jsfiddle.net/5CW7T/6/)

---

Since your parent div has width set to `2000px`, the later should have the same to be as wide as its parent not `100%` which fits browser screen.

Comment: Well, yes, that works. But it was a quick and simple example for my actual site. I have a header that is XXXpx wide and a header and footer that are both expected to span the whole window.

Comment: @Aaron Hathaway: Then you should specify same width for them. Let's know if that helps :)

Comment: I may be wrong, but I don't think so. I work on a 1920x1080 with my browser zoomed pretty far out. The banner is something like 1200px but on my screen this constitues only about 60% of the window. If I set the footer and header to be the 1200px as well then it would not span the whole width, as expected.

Comment: @Aaron Hathaway: If there is  parent element like `container` or `wrapper` with width set to `1920`, try giving a width of `100%` to footer, etc so that they inherit from their parent container. Make sure that footer div is inside the container.

Comment: Eventually got to the answer. Not quite sure if it was your help or not, but you did talk me through it. Outside communication is always helpful ;)

Comment: @Aaron Hathaway: That is glad to know :)